# How to modulo query on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp, boolean, booleanquery

I need modulo query because the data is to long and need to show in one screen only. Here's my dataset

```
     Name
1    they
2    ulti
3    they
4    set
5    djhd
6    tdh
7    t473
```

What I need is, `1 modulo 3` in this case

```
     Name
1    they
4    set
7    t473
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with modulo 3:

```
df = df[df.index % 3 == 1]
print (df)
   Name
1  they
4   set
7  t473
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.index % 3 )
Int64Index([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], dtype='int64')
```